# $P/Poly \setminus P$. What langugage does reside there?

Tags: complexity-theory

What language is in $P/Poly \setminus P$? I was thinking of it by hours but I cannot come with an idea. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

One example is the language
$$\{ 1^n : \text{the $n$th Turing machine halts on the empty input}\}.$$
This language has constant size circuits, but isn't computable.

Comment: Ok, what about computable languages in $P/poly \setminus P$?

Comment: This is an exercise that you can now complete on your own. The answer will look very similar.